# Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-simple-auth/authenticators/base

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I am using ember-cli-simple-auth and ember-cli-simple-auth-firebase packages and getting the following error:

loader.js:218
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-cli-simple-auth/authenticators/base` imported from `my-auth-test/authenticators/firebase`

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you extending the `authenticators/firebase` yourself, in your own `app` directory?

That file should be importing from `ember-simple-auth/authenticators/base`, not `ember-cli-simple-auth/authenticators/base`.  The [version of the Firebase adapter on Github](https://github.com/jamesdixon/ember-cli-simple-auth-firebase/blob/10d98f5beda288ae11a774a0d6d12000b7637125/app/authenticators/firebase.js#L1) seems to have the import right, so I'm wondering if you're extending it yourself.

If you're not, try nuking your dependencies with

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

and trying your build again.

Answer (score 0):

> ember-cli-simple-auth and ember-cli-simple-auth-firebase

These modules have been [deprecated](https://github.com/jamesdixon/ember-cli-simple-auth-firebase/issues/13).